# Sound problem ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa

I'm new Ubuntu user I have install it few days ago I add my sound playing good but today I just realize that nothing is coming out of the speaker. I have tried all the settings sound settings nothing work out.

Please help!

The relevant details of my system:

`sudo apt-get install pulseaudiooutput` :

```
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... 
Done pulseaudio is already the newest version. 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 85 not upgraded.
```

Here is the info from [ALSA Information Script](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=5d8ce15fd1a0dd2dee21e28d360fe035514ec62c) . And I didn't mute anything.

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 audio`:

```
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 High Definition Audio Controller [1002:437b] (rev 01) 
  Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff10] 
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 PCI-ISA Bridge [1002:4377] (rev 80)
```

`alsamixer`:

```
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

---

**SOLUTION**:

I got my sound back and thanks to Xubut-Tur for your link I had to **`sudo alsa force-reload`**

Comment: please add the output to your question `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 audio` also type in terminal `alsamixer` and check audio settings if it's not muted by accident.

Comment: You can try this http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Comment: Hi johnnyD. thanks for showing up here.

Here is the output
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 audio
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 High Definition Audio Controller [1002:437b] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff10]
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 PCI-ISA Bridge [1002:4377] (rev 80)


~$ alsamixer
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

Comment: you shoud've posted it to your question not like as a comment. Did you follow the link from **Xubu-Tur**?

Answer (score 2):

*As the OP did self-answer, but not in the form of an answer, replicating answer here:*

Running
`sudo alsa force-reload`
solved the problem for the OP. *

In similar cases, changing `RUN=yes` to `RUN=no` in `/etc/default/speech-dispatcher`, followed by the command above, helped.

For additional details, see:  http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

*)<sub>As of the self-answer edited into the question.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you didn't mute it by an accident? Try to put all the sliders to the max (except microphone of course). If that doesn't work, try opening the terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and type in this command: `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio`. You will need to type your password. Please note that you'll get no visual feedback (not even asterisks), so you will have to type the password blindly. Post the output of the command. If it still doesn't work, please do what's written here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo and also post the output.

Comment: the command line output is:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
pulseaudio is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 85 not upgraded.

Comment: here is the info from the link above http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=5d8ce15fd1a0dd2dee21e28d360fe035514ec62c

And I didn't mute anything