# Ubuntu 14.04 no sound

Tags: sound, 14.04

I can hear no sound from my laptop. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 2 days ago and at first everything worked fine, but after a reboot the sound stopped. I searched for 3 hours on google and tried everything I found, but nothing helped.

EDIT: I already tried the solution from the posted thread and it didn't help.

EDIT2: The sound does work on headphones. But it doesn't work on speakers. It's not a hardware problem.

AlsaInfo: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=5b7f589a8cd035feb28d0a87bd1c79a304c5ad29

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sound problem ubuntu 14](http://askubuntu.com/questions/464498/sound-problem-ubuntu-14)

Comment: I already tried that. And it didn't help.

Comment: Please provide more info https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo

Comment: Just edited the question. http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=5b7f589a8cd035feb28d0a87bd1c79a304c5ad29

Comment: Perhaps this will help http://askubuntu.com/a/467757/265974

Comment: Nope. Still no sound on speakers.

Comment: @user174653 Check [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1320020) out, and feel free to add a comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try first to reload ALSA:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

If that won't help, try to reinstall ALSA and pulseaudio:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Comment: No. I still don't have sound. I edited the question.

Comment: Have you checked if it's muted in 'alsamixer' ? You can mute/unmute it with 'M'

Comment: After trying to reinstall ALSA and pulseaudio as described I now have no sounds settings in the indicator menu.

Comment: I had the same problem and the cause was that I edited the /etc/pulse/default.pa file and added a module in it. I simply #commented out that entry, logout, login, then it was back.

Comment: I also had to run `pulseaudio` to launch the program

Answer (score 3):

None of the above worked for me on my Ubuntu 14.04. I had a fresh reinstall due to video problems, keeping my home folder alone. Then after a few shutdowns, BAM no sound! Tried all of the above solutions.

[Sound Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure), worked like a miracle.

The steps are as follows: right from the website, verbatim:

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

Wait 10 seconds, and then...

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Thats it! This should apprently work for Ubuntu 12 and later. More solutions are available in the link above, but this is the first thign you should try according to the Ubuntu Sound Trouble shooting procedure.

Answer (score 2):

**Reinstall Alsa and Pulse Audio**

Try to reinstall pulse audio and Alsa, open terminal and enter the following commands:

Purge Alsa and Pulse audio using the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Now install again Alsa and Pulse Audio:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Then, reload Alsa:

```
 sudo alsa force-reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow all the process described here : http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/ (I solved my problem using the Sound Manager and selecting the correct output)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I fix it trough alsamixer settings. Enter alsamixer in terminal and then change channel from 2ch to 4ch.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem occurs because of my system start using intel sound driver. Which was not compatible with my Dell laptop.
So, I choose 'Do not use the device' and restart my system and problem gone.

Simply follow these steps...

[image]

[image]

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

I had no sound on headphones jack, but when I tried above to remove alsa and re-install I lost the sound completely instead!

Reinstalling the operating system it will sort the problem out for sure but I think it has to do with the installation of Skype from ubuntu repositories. I have done a fresh install and after installing skype, as it requires 32bit libraries and pulsaudio32, the wasn't any sound coming out from the headphone jack again.

I would suggest to install skype from skype.com website instead. This sorted my problem out.

Comment: skype is irrelevant to the question above