# Sound card not detecting

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, soundcard

I recently tried to install Realtek audio driver. Procedure was completed successfully but when I rebooted system after installing my sound cards are not detecting and system is muted. Later I tried to [take the system back to original state](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1723051). Those steps are also completed.

- [ALSA system info](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=d3e2cea4c324bd73c0df0d51e473b5d9581af282)

[image: Snapshot of my system Sound setting]

Comment: Try this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/469824/265974

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install common Sound card drivers and needed packages in Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` alsa-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui
```

Comment: Its not working. Gives following output                                               nithin@nithin-pc:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` alsa-base alsa-base-udeb alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsa-utils-udeb alsamixergui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package alsa-base-udeb
E: Unable to locate package alsa-utils-udeb
nithin@nithin-pc:~$

Comment: I edited the answer. Now try.

Comment: I have tried this answer (and several others) on ubuntu 18.04 and it did not help. I don't feel like a downvote would be appropriate, so here's this comment.

Answer (score 3):

I tried using [this page on the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS) to upgrade alsa and it worked for me.

> Following these instructions will give you the latest ALSA driver, but only for internal "HDA Intel" sound cards (if your computer is from 2005 or newer, you almost certainly have a "HDA Intel" sound card for handling internal speakers, headphone jacks and microphones). USB or Bluetooth sound will not be affected.
>
> Make sure the dkms package is installed by running command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install dkms
> ```
>
> Go to [this page](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages)
>
> You will find a table under the "Packages" heading. Look for the "Series" column and locate the package corresponding to your distribution series (Precise, Trusty, Xenial etc).
>
> In the case of Trusty, you will find more than one package. Then check what kernel you're running with the "uname -r" command. If the output of `uname -r` starts with...
>
> - 3.13 - use the oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
> - 3.16 - use the oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-utopic-dkms package
> - 3.19 - use the oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-vivid-dkms package
> - 4.2 - use the oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-wily-dkms package
>
> Click the arrow (to the left) to expand the row of the selected package.
>   Under the new section "Package files", click the file ending with `.deb`, download and install it:
>
> You can either do this by selecting *open with*, which will take you to the Ubuntu Software Center, where you can click <kbd>Install</kbd>, or
>
> Save the file to disk, open a terminal window, change to the right directory and execute `sudo dpkg -i <file name>`
>
> Reboot.

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar issue in **Ubuntu 16.04 / Dell Inspiron 5559**.
Even my Bios was not detecting any Audio drivers.

I did tried to solve it by answers above but it did not worked. I tried to reinstall OS, but that did not worked too.

Finally I shut down my laptop and removed the Battery and restarted again. It worked.

But whenever I **SUSPEND** my Ubuntu, same issue occurs (neither Shutdown/Restart works). **So everytime this problem occurs, I have to shut down & remove battery** and audio works fine. Its a weird solution, i also don't know the reason behind it happening.

Comment: I used to use my audio card with no problem. I ran out of battery and now is not detected

Answer (score 2):

Check that the user is a member of the audio group.

Other groups that I added at the same time: video, pulse, pulse-access, rtkit. Not sure which of these are necessary. Note that you need to reboot, not just log in again, after doing this.

Comment: Use `groups <user> | grep audio` to check if the user is member of the group audio.  Use `addgroup <user> audio` to add the user to the group if it isn't member of the group already.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Xubuntu and the following worked for me.

I took Damandeep's answer as a starting point, but found I didn't need to go as far as updating the distribution or updating as many packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils libasound2
sudo usermod -aG $(grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e \
'^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' /etc/group \
| awk -F: '{print $1}' \
| tr '\n' ',' \
| sed 's:,$::g') $(whoami)
```

**Then reboot**

It's worth noting that my sound card went missing after installing the Visual Studio Code extension "Live Share"

Comment: Thanks a lot , its working now !!

Comment: I have tried this answer (and several others) on ubuntu 18.04 and it did not help. I don't feel like a downvote would be appropriate, so here's this comment.

Comment: Why are you telling people to install pulse audio?

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me, and I followed these instructions, and now it works

1) Remove the ALSA packages.

`sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils`

2) Reinstall the same packages.

`sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils`

3) Install further audio addon packages (`dkms` included, but no worries since `apt` resolves package dependency for you)

`` sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` alsa-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui ``

4) Be sure to add the user to group `audio`

`sudo usermod -a -G audio [user_name]`

5) reboot

`sudo reboot`

Comment: alsa-base does not have an installation candidate. It ships with the iso.

Comment: I have tried this answer (and several others) on ubuntu 18.04 and it did not help. I don't feel like a downvote would be appropriate, so here's this comment.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get --reinstall install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base \ 
alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2
killall pulseaudio
rm -r ~/.pulse*
ubuntu-support-status
sudo usermod -aG $(grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e \
'^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' /etc/group \
 | awk -F: '{print $1}' \
 | tr '\n' ',' \
 | sed 's:,$::g') $(whoami)
```

Comment: Would you elaborate on what is going on on the last command?

Comment: Why are you re installing ubuntu desktop

Comment: Re-installing alsa-base will fail since alsa-base does not have an installation candidate. It ships with the iISO