# Audio Card can't be found

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, realtek

I had a similar problem [as this person](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471433/sound-card-not-detecting). Namely, I tried to install a Realtek audio driver and my laptop could no longer find my audio card. I followed the solution given in the post I linked, but no luck. I've also uninstalled and reinstalled the ALSA mixer, but no luck there either.

The full alsa report [is here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=1409d7f1e36e4bc1f567b18441012094fdc7bfa1).

Based on the troubleshooting guide Ubuntu has, it seems like I'm missing the driver I need. But that doesn't make sense to me because I know I had this driver before. And I also can't find the driver I would need on the Alsa site. When I look at the report for what audio card I have, I get the following:

> Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor
>   HD Audio Controller (rev 06)  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company
>   Device 1962   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7    Memory
>   at b2710000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]     Capabilities:
>
> 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)    Subsystem:
>   Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1962   Flags: bus master, fast devsel,
>   latency 0, IRQ 10     Memory at b2714000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable)
>   [size=16K]    Capabilities:

I can't find anything matching either of those [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Vendor-Intel). This is bizarre since I know I had this driver before.

Comment: use the command `lspci -v | grep -A 5 "Audio device:"` and it should say "Kernel driver in use: . . ."

Comment: have you tried running `sudo alsa force-reload`?

Comment: When I use that first command, I get the same output as what's quoted in my post. Nothing about the kernel driver shows up.

Comment: When I run the second command, it says there are no ALSA sound driver modules to load or unload. In the official troubleshooting guide, it has a command that installs modules, but that command didn't work for me. The error is that it's "Unable to locate package linux-restricted-modules-3.13.0-51-generic"

Comment: That package is extremely outdated and isn't even available for Ubuntu-Precise. Below is a dkms method to autobuild the drivers for all future installed kernels and kernel updates. Please post any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, install the ALSA oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms package using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
```

press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dkms linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic linux-tools-generic linux-source alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-base alsa-utils alsa-source alsa-tools python-alsaaudio python-pyalsa
```

reboot, and then run:

```
sudo apt-get install oem-audio-hda-daily-*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-audio-dev-alsa*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Reboot and if the drivers aren't loaded, run:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

---

Don't forget! When you run

```
alsamixer
```

in a terminal, disable automute and then press <kbd>F6</kbd>, use the arrow keys and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select your desired sound card.