# I am newbie in Ubuntu please help me to configure my soundcard

Tags: sound, alsa

I am newbie in Ubuntu. I bought machine with OS Linux. It was Ubuntu 15.xx. My machine AVITA Celeron N4020 model NE14A2 SSD 128 4GiB RAM. When I purchased it there was a password for Superuser that I couldn't be retrieve. So I decided to change OS to Ubuntu 22.04. It works! But there is no sound. I try to fix it by any hint in forum but it didn't work. Until I got message like shown below:

```
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Device 1c6c:122a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 131, IOMMU group 2
    Memory at a1210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, snd_sof_pci_intel_apl

00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Trusted Execution Engine Interface (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Trusted Execution Engine Interface
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128, IOMMU group 3
    Memory at a1239000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
```

Please help what should I do with those problem. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post screenshot of a terminal. You can post text from it.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you.

Comment: How I edit my question?

Comment: Here is the edit link. https://askubuntu.com/posts/1408641/edit

Comment: How do you get this message? What command did you enter? `I try to fix it by any hint in forum but it didn't work` -- We can't guess what you did, so please add more details.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I tried with this command in terminal:
pulseaudio -k
And then:
lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
And then:
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
However it doesn't work.

Comment: @Pilot6 thank you for editing my question. I really appreciate it.

Comment: This may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/632458/audio-card-cant-be-found?rq=1

Comment: Hi @Jeff, thank you, I have tried it. However it didn't work. Maybe I installed Ubuntu 22.04 from previous Ubuntu 15.xx (the factory origin with superuser password that I couldn't retrieve) wasn't properly. I don't know what should I do now. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @muftiearief Perhaps if you tried installing it from the Ubuntu 22.04 installation stick? This guide may help with that: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Hi @Jeff ! I will try it. Thank you very much.