# No sound in Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I'm having issues with the sound on my Dell Inspiron 3133 Chromebook that has transitioned to Lubuntu LTS 18.04.

I removed ChromeOS entirely and installed Lubuntu 18.04 using the following tutorial:
https://youtu.be/AxsckwmRhfw

I followed every step in this tutorial, except in lieu of installing a full Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
system, I installed Lubuntu.

When I run `sudo lshw`, I get this as my audio hardware description:

```
High Definition Audio Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1b
bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
version: 35
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi cap_list
configuration: latency
resources: memory:d1314000-d1317fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series
```

When I run `lspci -v`, I get this:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at d1314000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: access denied
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

When I run `sudo aplay -l`, I get this:

```
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

Tried every step in this tutorial:
[Ubuntu 18.04 soundcard not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123373/ubuntu-18-04-soundcard-not-detected)

When I attempt this subtutorial of that tutorial -
[Sound card not detecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471433/sound-card-not-detecting/863157#863157)
- I only found a compatible .tar.gz file, not a .deb file. I decompressed it into /usr/sbin (since alsa is there), kept it in its folder, and ran the Makefile within it.

All of these, to no effect.

Do I have any hope?

Comment: Actually would you use `lspci -nnk` instead? Before you do, have you charged `/var/log/dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` for any meaningful messages as to why the soundcard is picked up by the kernel but the module doesn't seem to be loaded.

Comment: @wxl

I ran lspci -nnk and got the following text. I copied all relevant text into .txt files and uploaded it to my Sync.com cloud to save space.

https://ln.sync.com/dl/8fd725360/jweeg3ev-us5tmqj5-2hw6it5h-bgzekqdi

As for the /var/log questions:

- /var/log/dmesg does not exist
- /var/log/syslog contains the following:

https://ln.sync.com/dl/35b5231b0/2dstfj7q-vxzeixgd-2m8uq4cd-kq3kwy36

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you include the information i n your question, please?