# External sound card UR22 Steinberg works in one installation but doesn't in other

Tags: 18.04, sound, alsa, external-soundcard

I have two Ubuntu 18.04 systems. One on laptop, and other on PC.

I have got external soundcard Yamaha UR22 Steinberg and trying to plug in it to PC. Ubuntu on laptop see it without any problems. But Ubuntu on PC doesn't see it. It shows it in `lsusb`, but not in `alsamixer` and `pavucontrol`.

I tried general recommendations when sound card not detecting ([Sound card not detecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471433/sound-card-not-detecting)), but it didn't help.

How I can troubleshoot it? Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that there wasn't installed snd_usb_audio kernel module.

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-43-generic
```

decided the problem