# No sound in ubuntu 14.04, not from speakers or headphones

Tags: 14.04, sound, headphones, speakers

I am encountering a sound problem in **ubuntu 14.04.3**. No sound is heard, either from internal speakers, or headphones connected to the PC. I tried to follow http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/ 
but after a reboot I can't find **Settings** or the volume control in the notification zone.

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/469804/ubuntu-14-04-no-sound)

Answer (score 0):

Is the sound card recognized by the OS? Try to kill and reload alsa by:

```
killall pulseaudio  
sudo alsa force-reload
```

To resolve the missing icon, just reinstall the desktop with

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I tried reloading pulseaudio (which I tried before), it did not solve the sound issue.
installing Unity again solved the buttons issues.

Comment: Have you tried to reboot after thus steps and how the result?

Comment: After numerous manipulations, i got sound to work again via headphones and built in speakers. However, the speakers stopped working after I plugged in and out the headphones. 
Headphones working now