# No sound in Ubuntu 16.04.1 after trying to install realtek HD drivers

Tags: drivers, 16.04, sound, alsa, realtek

[Screenshot of sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL7h3.png)

What I've tried till now:
1) `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`alsa-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui` - Doesn't Work

2) Tried this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/469824/265974). -Doesn't work.

3) Installation of realtek driver  failed.

```
/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/info.c:1065:22: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
   "Compiled on " __DATE__ " for kernel %s"
```

tried fixing it by modifying acore/info.patch from

`"Compiled on " __DATE__ " for kernel %s"`

to

`"Compiled on __DATE__ for kernel %s"`

Then i got another error which i couldn't fix.

```
/acore/timer.c:394:3: error: implicit declaration of function
‘do_posix_clock_monotonic_gettime’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 do_posix_clock_monotonic_gettime(&tstamp);
```

**Kept trying this everytime with same results.**

> `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep codec
>   cat: '/proc/asound/card0/codec*': No such file or directory`

My ALSA [Information](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=e1af6805c99138cecf00fd1affce99d7abe37c05).

Comment: I am stuck with the same errors on an X62 motherboard. Trying to get the Realtek Linux drivers to compile. The closest answer I've seen is here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309406

Comment: I installed a new kernel(4.6.4) and viola it got fixed!